# Change header/footer on chapter pages

Tags: header-footer

I want to change the header/footer of every page starting with "chapter". Now the header and footer of chapter pages are empty, but I will change it to only the page number in the middle of the footer.

For example, here is a MWE:

```
\documentclass[
ngerman,
12pt,
BCOR=0mm,
DIV=calc,
bibliography=totoc,
listof=entryprefix,
listof=totoc,
headings=optiontoheadandtoc,
captions=tableheading,
chapterprefix=true
]{scrreprt}

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{babel}

\usepackage[a4paper]{geometry}
\geometry{left=3.5cm,right=3.5cm,top=3cm,bottom=3cm}
\usepackage[headsepline,automark]{scrlayer-scrpage}         
\renewcommand*{\chaptermarkformat}{Kapitel~\thechapter.~}
\clearscrheadfoot                               
\ohead[]{\pagemark}
\ihead[]{\rightmark}
\usepackage{blindtext}

\begin{document}
    \chapter{Test}
    \blindtext[5]
\end{document}
```

Header of "normal" pages now (footer empty):

[image]

And the pagestyle of the first page in a chapter:

[image]

Thank you!!!

Comment: Not related to your question, but do you want to have a full stop after the chapter number in the header? You don't have it in the chapter headline as it is the preferred way to set it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Either use `\clearmainofpairofpagestyles` to only clean the settings for page style `scrheadings`

```latex
\clearmainofpairofpagestyles
\ohead{\pagemark}
\ihead{\rightmark}
```

or use `\cfoot[\pagemark]{}` to add the page number in footer for page style `plain`:

```latex
\clearpairofpagestyles
\ohead{\pagemark}
\ihead{\rightmark}
\cfoot[\pagemark]{}
```

Example:

```latex
\documentclass[
ngerman,
12pt,
BCOR=0mm,
DIV=calc,
bibliography=totoc,
listof=entryprefix,
listof=totoc,
headings=optiontoheadandtoc,
captions=tableheading,
chapterprefix=true
]{scrreprt}

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
%\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}% only needed with older TeX distributions
\usepackage{babel}

\usepackage[a4paper]{geometry}
\geometry{left=3.5cm,right=3.5cm,top=3cm,bottom=3cm}
\usepackage[headsepline,automark]{scrlayer-scrpage}
\renewcommand*{\chaptermarkformat}{Kapitel~\thechapter.~}
\clearpairofpagestyles
\ohead{\pagemark}
\ihead{\rightmark}
\cfoot[\pagemark]{}
\usepackage{blindtext}

\begin{document}
\chapter{Test}
\Blindtext
\end{document}
```

Remark: `\clearscrheadfoot` is depraceted. It only exists for reasons of compatibility with the outdated package `scrpage2`.